# Can I conditionally activate the Git prompt depending on the repository I'm in?

Tags: git, git-bash, bash

I'm using the built-in [git prompt shell script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) to improve my Bash prompt.

```
. ~/git-completion.bash
. ~/git-prompt.sh

export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
```

I have this one enormous enterprise application repository (100s of thousands of files, a very deep directory tree, the `.git` directory is almost 2 GB). The prompt is taking a very long time to complete.

Is there some way to tell `git-prompt.sh` to ignore this workspace? Either by flags or in my `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jubobs's answer got me thinking... I wanted to test for some condition that the large repository would satisfy. I didn't want to limit myself to one repository. And I needed this to work in all sub-directories of those repos.

I explored the `git` command itself. It does a bunch of work to search the directory tree for the `.git` folder. For example, this command will exit 0 if you're in a git repo and non-zero if not.

```
$ git rev-parse --git-dir &>/dev/null
```

That's neat, but not enough. I wanted to know if I'm in a git repo and ignoring the prompt. But, I didn't want to combine complicated conditionals. Then I thought about using a custom git config key.

```
$ git config --local prompt.ignore 1
```

I could run this test to see if it's non-empty. I should figure out how to test for 0 or empty vs. non-empty, but this is a start.

```
$ [[ -z $(git config prompt.ignore) ]]
```

That has the best features of all. I could add this to any repo. It participates in "is this a git repo?" discovery and answering the prompt ignore question, all in one!

I baked that into my `.bashrc` like so

```
function __my_ps1 {
  if [[ -z $(git config prompt.ignore) ]];
  then
    __git_ps1 "$PROMPT_PRE" "$PROMPT_POST"
  fi
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=__my_ps1
```

I'm using the Git Bash prompt from the Git for Windows package and it has a pretty friendly prompt already. I wonder if I would need to provide an `else` branch for that prompt command in any other shell.

Answer (score 4):

### Define a conditional Git prompt

Take a look at the suggested Bash prompt definition in [`git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) (but without the user and host, because they take too much space, and are irrelvant to your question):

```
PS1='[\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

Nothing prevents you from inserting a test in the command substitution, like so:

```
PS1='[\W$(if true; then __git_ps1 " (%s)"; fi)]\$ '
```

although this example is rather silly. Using this idea, you can define a conditional Git prompt such that,

- if you're *outside* the working tree of the offending repo, the Git prompt is activated, and
- if you're *inside* the repo in question, the Git prompt is deactived.

The following Bash prompt definition does exactly that:

```
export PS1='[\W$(if [[ ! $PWD/ = $OFFENDINGDIR/* ]]; then __git_ps1 " (%s)"; fi)]\$ '
```

where `OFFENDINGDIR` is a variable that must be assigned the path to the root directory of the offending repo.

### Example

Assume that `~/projectA` is the offending repo. For information, here is my default prompt definition:

```
PS1='\W\$ '
```

Very simple; no Git prompt whatsoever. Now, let's `cd` to the offending repository:

```sh
~$ cd projectA

# Let's check that we are indeed in a Git repo:
projectA$ git branch
* master

# Now let's set up our conditional Git prompt:
projectA$ export OFFENDINGDIR=$PWD
projectA$ export PS1='[\W$(if [[ ! $PWD/ = $OFFENDINGDIR/* ]]; then __git_ps1 " (%s)"; fi)]\$ '

# Our Bash prompt changes accordingly...
[projectA]$
# ... but notice that it contains no branch info (as desired).

# However, if we cd to another repo...
[projectA]$ cd ../projectB
[projectB (master)] $
# ... the Git prompt is there, as desired!
```

Answer (score 3):

The built-in git prompt shell script has per-repository options you can set to speed up the prompt.

Set `bash.showDirtyState` to `false` to [disable checking for changes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa25c82427ae70aebf3b8f970f2afd54e9a2a8c6/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L38-L42):

```
$ git config --local --add bash.showDirtyState false
```

Set `bash.showUntrackedFiles` to `false` to [stop checking for untracked files](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa25c82427ae70aebf3b8f970f2afd54e9a2a8c6/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L48-L53):

```
$ git config --local --add bash.showUntrackedFiles false
```

Set `bash.showUpstream` to the empty string to [stop comparing HEAD with its upstream](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa25c82427ae70aebf3b8f970f2afd54e9a2a8c6/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L73-L76):

```
$ git config --local --add bash.showUpstream ''
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this on a problematic repo and it seems to have done quite a difference. (I’m using Fish shell but it worked fine anyway.)